# Unable to route to test pages using Wagtail Factories and Factory Boy

Tags: django, wagtail, django-testing

I'm trying to implement factory boy and wagtail factories to generate tests for the blog section of my site, at /blog/, which uses Wagtail CMS. However, I'm getting a 404 error when doing `self.assertPageIsRoutable` on the `BlogIndexPage` and `CategoryIndexPage`.

I'm creating a Site. The root of the site is set to BlogIndexPage, then CategoryIndexPage is created as a child of BlogIndexPage. To my knowledge, `wagtail_factories.PageFactory` handles the creation of nodes and parents.

**Factory**

```
class BlogIndexPageFactory(wagtail_factories.PageFactory):

    title = "Blog Index"
    intro = "Welcome to the Blog"
    slug = "blog"

    class Meta:
        model = models.BlogIndexPage


class CategoryIndexPageFactory(wagtail_factories.PageFactory):

    title = factory.sequence(lambda n: f"Category {n}")
    intro = factory.sequence(lambda n: f"Welcome to Category {n}")

    class Meta:
        model = models.CategoryIndexPage


class BlogPageFactory(wagtail_factories.PageFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = models.BlogPage


class SiteFactoryDefault(wagtail_factories.SiteFactory):

    is_default_site = True
    root_page = factory.SubFactory(BlogIndexPageFactory)
```

**Test**

```
class TestBlogIndex(WagtailPageTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.site = SiteFactoryDefault.create()
        cls.index = cls.site.root_page
        cls.categories = CategoryIndexPageFactory.create_batch(4, parent=cls.index)

    def test_can_create_child(self):
        assert CategoryIndexPage.can_create_at(self.index)

    def test_category_route(self):
        for category in self.categories:
            self.assertPageIsRoutable(category)
```

**Trace**

```
FAIL: test_category_route (blog.tests.TestBlogIndex)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\models\__init__.py", line 1664, in route
    subpage = self.get_children().get(slug=child_slug)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 650, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
wagtail.models.Page.DoesNotExist: Page matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\test\utils\page_tests.py", line 200, in assertPageIsRoutable
    page, args, kwargs = site.root_page.localized.specific.route(
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\contrib\routable_page\models.py", line 162, in route
    return super().route(request, path_components)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\models\__init__.py", line 1666, in route
    raise Http404
django.http.response.Http404

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\blog\tests.py", line 26, in test_category_route
    self.assertPageIsRoutable(category)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\test\utils\page_tests.py", line 214, in assertPageIsRoutable
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: Failed to route to "/" for CategoryIndexPage "Category 1". A Http404 was raised for path: "http://localhost:81/blog/category-1/".
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a similar 404 issue creating test pages using wagtail factories.

Comment: @quadrismegistus No, unfortunately I wasn't able to find a solution so I stopped using it.